# sqlite: avoid full table scan while querying one to many databse

Tags: sqlite

Lets say I have two tables in a database:

```
user:
---------------
|  name | id  |
|-------|-----|
|  foo  |  1  |
|  bar  |  2  |
---------------

comments:
 ------------------
|  comment  |  id |
|-----------------|
| comment 1 |  1  |
| comment 2 |  1  |
| comment 3 |  1  |
| comment 4 |  1  |
| comment 5 |  1  |
| comment 1 |  2  |
 ------------------
```

Lets says I want to pull up all comments made by `foo` so my query will be

`SELECT c.comment from comments c, user u WHERE u.name='foo' and c.id = u.id`

will the above query do a FULL table scan on comments table to get comments made by user `foo` or is there a better query to optimize this and avoid a full table lookup ? Should I create index for these tables ?

Comment: Try to avoid comma seperated JOINS!

Comment: Why do you think SQLite is doing a full table lookup? Did you check the execution plan? And although using an explicit `JOIN` operator won't (or shouldn't) change the performance, it's better coding style than using the out-dated implicit joins in the `where` clause

Comment: Read the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add an index on comment/Id in your table comments in order to optimize your query speed.

But it depends on the volume of data or the volume expected in future time. Sometimes you will never need indexes in a small table that will never grow.
It's up to you to think of the usage and evolution of your tables.

Therefore "Should I create ... " : it depends !